# Inconsistent compiler behavior

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, template-meta-programming

I'm seeing some inconsistencies between gcc, clang and msvc 2015/2017. The following fails on msvc but not gcc or clang. These meta-functions should return the type of a parameter in a function signature type:

```
template <int _ParamNum, typename _Ty> struct _get_parameter;
template <typename _ReturnT, typename _HeadT, typename ... _TailT> 
   struct _get_parameter<0, _ReturnT(_HeadT, _TailT...)>
{
  using type = _HeadT;
};
template <int _ParamNum, typename _ReturnT, typename _HeadT, typename ... _TailT> 
   struct _get_parameter<_ParamNum, _ReturnT(_HeadT, _TailT...)> 
{
  using type = 
    typename _::template _get_parameter<_ParamNum - 1, _ReturnT(_TailT...)>::type;
};
```

called with something like:

```
using param_type = typename _get_parameter<0, decltype(printf)>::type;
```

I'm inclined to think its an MSVC bug but I hope somebody can eyeball a problem with the code instead.

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

Well I stand corrected: http://rextester.com/XZEL74804 it seems to be some strange interaction with the larger code base.

Comment: what is `_` in `_::`?

Comment: The signature for `printf` is `int (const char *, ...)` with the `...` having no type, so how would we deduce `_TailT` in the code above? The clang version built into MSVC2017 also goes for the undefined base template as the best match.

Comment: _ is a internal detail namespace

Comment: @BoPersson the first partial specialization is selected because it's more specialized with the explicit '0'. _HeadT becomes const char * and _TailT... becomes a variadic type (I think). But it shouldn't matter, its just for illustrative purpose and not used anyway.